# Efficiently read data in python (only one line)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, io

For a upcoming programming competition I solved a few of the tasks of former competitions. 
Each task looks like this: We get a bunch of in-files (each containing 1 line of numbers and strings, f.e. "2 15 test 23 ..."), and we have to build a program and return some computed values.

These in-files can be quite large: for instance 10 MB. 
My code is the following:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    input_data = f.read().split()
```

This is quite slow. I quess mostly because of the split method. Is there a faster way?

Comment: You can use `readline()` to read the first line, and if it's large data and you know the size of then instead of slitting the entire line just use `buffer = f.readline()[:number_of_bytes]`, You can also read specific number of bytes like that `f.read(number_of_bytes)`

Comment: you can't assign to `in` that is a syntax error

Comment: @KobiK it is a one-line file

Comment: @wim it was just an example, corrected it to another variable name

Comment: Do you need to use all the data in the file to compute the desired values? If not, how do you find the data you need? If you only need to use some of the data, and that needed data is at (or after) a known offset you can speed things up considerably by using `seek()`.

Comment: Yes, I use all data for the computation.

Answer (score 1):

What you have already looks like the best way for plain text IO on a one-line file.

10 MB of plain text is fairly large, if you need some more speedup you could consider pickling the data in a binary format instead of a plain text format.  Or if it is very repetitive data, you could store it compressed.

Comment: +1 - I can think of more memory efficient ways to do it, but I can't think of any that'd be "faster"...

Answer (score 1):

If one of your input files contains independent tasks (that is, you can work on a couple of tokens of the line at a time, without knowing tokens further ahead), you can do reading and processing in lockstep, by simpy not reading the whole file at once.

```
def read_groups(f):
    chunksize= 4096 #how many bytes to read from the file at once
    buf= f.read(chunksize)
    while buf:
        if entire_group_inside(buf): #checks if you have enough data to process on buf
            i= next_group_index(buf) #returns the index on the next group of tokens
            group, buf= buf[:i], buf[i:]
            yield group
        else:
            buf+= f.read(chunksize)

with open(filename) as f:
    for data in read_groups(f):
        #do something
```

This has some advantages:

- You don't need to read the whole file into memory (which, for 10 MB on a desktop, probably doesn't matter much)
- if you do a lot of processing on each group of tokens, it *may* lead to better performance, as you'll have alternating I/O and CPU bound tasks. Modern OSs use sequential file prefetching to optimize file linear access, so, in practice, if you lockstep I/O and CPU, your I/O will end up being executed in parallel by the OS. Even if your OS has no such functionality, if you have a modern disk, it'll probably cache sequential access to blocks.

If you don't have much processing, though, your task is fundamentally I/O bound, and there isn't much you can do to speed it up as it stands, as wim said - other than rethinking your input data format

Comment: @joaquin you're right, I missed that. The technique is valid for any separable chunks of data, though - I've edited the question to explain it better